# "Non-exhaustive pattern in function" of a very simple function?

Tags: haskell, recursion

Hello stackoverflow community,

I have a rather simple piece of code that is getting a strange error.  Here is my code:

```
multiplyByTwo 0 = 1
myltiplyByTwo x = 2 * multiplyByTwo (x-1)
```

as you can see, it is simple recursion.  I am getting the "Non-exhaustive pattern in function
multiplyByTwo" exception.  I do not understand why I am getting this, as I have already set the lowest value `multiplyByTwo 0 = 1` therefore I would guess that the function is not calling itself after that point. What I am saying is that I do not understand why this pattern is "non-exhaustive".  I am assuming that the number you enter for x is positive.

thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: You're aware that your function computes 2^x, not 2x?

Comment: yes i am aware that my function does 2 to the power of the input 'x'

Comment: in addition think what would your function do, if you passed it negative values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a typo in the second line:

```
myltiplyByTwo x = 2 * multiplyByTwo (x-1)
 ^
```

thus that defines a new function, and `multiplyByTwo` is only defined for the argument 0.

Comment: oh wow, look at that.  Thank you very much, that was a rather silly mistake.

Comment: Happens every day of the week. Now you know what to look for next time.

Comment: That's one reason I wish it was an error not to write some sort of declaration for each function, even if not a full type signature.

Comment: @pigworker One of the reasons indeed. Compiling with `-Wall -Werror` certainly has its benefits.